# Why does the truffle console not print correct variable in solidity smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I am a beginner in programming Ethereum smart contracts using solidity and truffle. I made a simple smart contract to deploy that sets a variable equal to 1000000, as shown below:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.8.0;
contract CelesteToken{
uint256 public totalSupply;
  function ClesteToken()public{
    totalSupply = 1000000;
}
}
```

In the truffle console I used the following commands:

```
CelesteToken.deployed().then(function(i){token =i;})
token.totalSupply().then(function(s){totalSupply =s;})
totalSupply.toNumber()
```

However instead of returning 1000000 as per the code, it returns 0. I am not sure why this is happening, can anyone help?

Comment: Your constructor is never called.

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing

```
function ClesteToken()public{
    totalSupply = 1000000;
}
```

to

```
constructor () public {
    totalSupply = 1000000;
}
```